# how to create a new line in the same text view?

Tags: android

i think you may get the idea of wat i'm trying to do if you look at the code:

here the complication is that i cannot create another textview for another line....

```
s8="hello";
t12=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.solid);     
t12.setText("check"+"/n"+s8);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct notation for newline is `\n` not `/n`. TextViews in Android are multi-line enabled by default, so no other magic should be required.

Comment: Silly mistakes happen to the best of us.